# Reset BIOS password in Toshiba Satellite C50D-B

Tags: bios, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba satellite C50D-B. I need to no how to find the BIOS pins on the motherboard. I've tried tapping ESC on power up with no luck and also tried holding O on power.

Does anyone have a picture of this laptop's motherboard to show me where to find the pins to short the BIOS password?

Comment: Think your CAPS LOCK is stuck...

Comment: yes sorry about that

Comment: Then please [edit] your post and fix it. Also please share your research.

Answer (score 0):

Remove hardrive and RAM, then short circuit the pins marked on the picture and plugin the power.

[image]

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzs_hzbfeZc